# move_uploaded_file not working with 'larger' files

Tags: php

I have a webpage that allows users to upload a profile picture.
All is working with jpgs until a size of around 2MBs.
Larger files wont be uploaded into tmp, though.

So I checked some settings:

```
echo 'post_max_size = ' . ini_get('post_max_size') . "\n";
echo 'memory_limit = ' . ini_get('memory_limit') . "\n";
// results in:
post_max_size = 8M
memory_limit = 128M
```

So that should not be the problem.

Also I checked that the file is actually sent via ajax,
but the request headers include
`Content-Length:2904576`, so I assume the file (with 2.9MB) is actually sent. Furthermore I have this in the request payload:
`Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="bg.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg`

For smaller files I can see the tmp file appearing shortly in the tmp folder of my php installation - NOT for the failing larger files.

Which means something in between is blocking the files from beeing uploaded.

Does anybody have an idea what else I could check?

*ConfigInfo:
local php 5.4 on local webserver (EasyPHP DevServer 14.1.VC11)*

Comment: Check (and increase) also `upload_max_filesize` configuration option

Comment: thanks, @MiroDavid, It was set to 2MB. I gues that was it!! (didn't know this also existed, a bit redundant to post_max_size...)

Comment: wanna make that an answer?

Comment: not at all redundant `post_max_size` is the max size of the  whole post. `upload_max_filesize` just the file(if any

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, you must increase the value of both variables in php.ini (*post_max_size* and *upload_max_filesize*)